# Как преобразовать HTML таблицу в картинку (jpeg/png) силами php?

Tags: php, html

**Дано:**

HTML код таблицы.

**Задача:**

Получить эту таблицу в виде картинки.

**Задача подробнее:**

Эту таблицу (распарсенный `HTML` код с сайта) надо отобразить в виде сообщения `telegram`-бота. Телеграм не поддерживает большую часть `HTML` тэгов, включая таблицы. Решил вот так проблему решить: получаем код таблицы, преобразуем в картинку, отсылаем картинку таблицы.

**Что сам сделал:**

Почитал en-SO и решил пойти по пути `HTML-PDF-IMAGE`
Нашёл [php-либу](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/), получающую на входе `HTML` код таблицы и выдающей `*.pdf` документ с ней. Даже стили можно использовать (sic!).
Остался последний шаг - преобразовать `pdf` в картинку.

**Проблема:**

По запросу типа

> pdf to image php

выдаются только советы [использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467805/3212712) некие **ImageMagick** и **GhostScript**. Но, насколько я понял, они не подойдут мне, т.к. у меня не выделенный сервер, а просто хостинг с `php`, а эти модули надо в систему прямо ставить.

**Вопрос:**

Так таки есть ли способ получить силами непроапгрейженного всякими прогами `php` изображение из `pdf` или я вообще не по тому пути иду?

**P.S.**

Возможно стоит вообще другую [либу](http://html2pdf.fr/en/example) попробовать?..

Comment: Возможно стоит сложить код таблицы в открытый доступ с секретной ссылкой, получить эту ссылку, натравить на неё сервис типа https://screenshotlayer.com, удалить таблицу и радоваться? Чейнинг какой-то большой выходит для получения картинки. Да и нормальной картинки без движка рендера не получится.

Comment: @Other, звучит отлично, но, к сожалению, оно платно, а монетизация будущего бота под **большим** вопросом(

Comment: 100/month - может и мало, но кто мешает по истечению лимита регать ещё акк?

Comment: @Other, как я понял 100 на акк за всё время его существования и чрез месяц оно не пополнится( Ну и, боюсь, эти 100 раз на акк могут и за день уйти, а автоматизировать создание новых акков сложно да и неэтично)

Comment: Нет, это месячный лимит, см. всплывающую подсказку. Автоматизацию один раз сделать и не волноваться ещё долго. А этика... ничего такого, что сайт сам бы не давал (возможность бесплатного аккуанта), никто не берёт.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=web+page+to+png+online -> http://www.pdfconvertonline.com/webpage-to-png-online.html ; http://web-capture.net/ ; дальше лень искать.

Comment: @Other, спасибо, как раз в этом направлении тоже копал) Вот у гугла тоже есть подобная штука, но с ограничениями [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22342840/3212712). Там, правда, в виде json картинка возвращается.

Comment: @Other, я в сетевых запросах не очень разбираюсь... Я по приведённым вами ссылкам смогу программно передавать адрес сформированной мною страницы с таблицей и получать обратно картинку? Типа `file_get_contents(ТУТ_АДРЕС_СЕРВИСА_И_ПАРАМЕТРЫ_ЗАПРОСА)`?

Comment: Гугл помог в нахождении более удобных сервисов, так что хоть за это спасибо. Попробуйте решить Ваш вопрос этим методом, у себя это можно решить вроде с помощью подобного: http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/ Но раз это хостинг...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39533/discussion-between-other-and-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно стоит сложить код таблицы в открытый доступ с секретной ссылкой, получить эту ссылку, натравить на неё сервис типа `screenshotlayer.com`, удалить таблицу и радоваться?

`screenshotlayer.com` удобный (API и плюшки), но платный.
Сервисы типа `pdfconvertonline.com/webpage-to-png-online.html`, `web-capture.net` бесплатны, но нужно проделать чуть больше движений чтобы получить картинку: сформировать запрос, распарсить ответ и скачать картинку.

---

Для примера (`pdfconvertonline.com/`):

- POST `http://s2.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/convert-webpage-win.php`
- Тело: `websiteurl=google.com&filetype=PNG&source=WEENYSOFT&convert=Convert+Now%21`
- Вернётся `302` на что-то типа `http://www.pdfconvertonline.com/results.php?name=00i27-mv4a4.png&ser=2`.
- В коде будет ссылка на картинку:

  ```
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://s2.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/00i27-mv4a4.png" target="_new">00i27-mv4a4.png</a>
  ```

---

Вот рабочий код от ТС, делающий запрос на вышепомянутый сайт с нужными заголовками и выводящий результирующий HTML код страницы, коя содержит ссылку на требуемый PNG. Останется только распарсить ответ для получения ссылки на изображение и скачать его к себе на сервер.

```
<?php
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://s2.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/convert-webpage-win.php',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(websiteurl=>'LINK_TO_HTML_PAGE_WITH_TABLE_IN_IT.html', filetype=>PNG, source=>WEENYSOFT, convert=>Convert+Now%21 ))
));
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

echo $response;
```

---

И опять код от автора ответа:
Для парсинга ответа, используем [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Код страницы ответа в $response

$dom = str_get_html($response);

$link = $dom->find('#item_1 a', 0); // Это ссылка на картинку

printf("Your image: <a href='%s'>%s</a>", $link->href, $link->innertext);
// $image = file_get_contents($link->href);
```

Comment: А если не пользоваться сервисами сторонними, а самому скриншотить??=))
   <pre> <code> 
    <?php
    $im = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
   </code></pre>