# Создание картинки из html-тегов с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html

Я знаю что в php есть что-то что позволяет делать рисунки, на основе текста, заливок и векторов
Но можно ли допустим создать картинку из оформленного div блока?

Comment: Вы хотите рендерить HTML+CSS  в картинку? На php это будет не просто.

Comment: Я лишь спросил: "можно ли", но если это очень трудно...или того не стоит тогда ладно, останется вопрос, а можно ли вообще такое провернуть но не с помощью php?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=php+html+to+pdf&lr=219&redircnt=1463478871.1

Comment: @MaximPro это можно сделать даже в браузере, [через canvas/foreignObject](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/), но с некотрыми ограничениями

Comment: Что вы под этим подразумеваете?.... просто пару слоев с разными картинками стыковать можно....но я полагаю вы хотите чтото другое?

Answer (score 1):

Вот аналогичный вопрос: [Как преобразовать HTML таблицу в картинку (jpeg/png) силами php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521881/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-jpeg-png-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-php)

Кратко:

1. Поместите нужный HTML в отдельный файл на сервере.
2. Скормите ссылку на него сайту, делающему скриншоты сайтов.
3. Получите в ответе ссылку на файл-скриншот.

Comment: интересная идея

Comment: @MaximPro, во всяком случае у меня это работает отлично.

Comment: а сервис не подкините?

Comment: @MaximPro, в ответе по ссылке есть ссылки и даже конкретный рабочий пример с URL

Comment: А если не пользоваться сервисами сторонними, а самому скриншотить??=))
   <pre> <code> 
    <?php
    $im = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
   </code></pre>