# Создание изображения круга с буквой в центре

Tags: php, графика, gd

Нужно создать изображение круга с зеленым фоном и размером 50х50 пикселей. В центре символ `I` белым цветом. Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: Смотри в сторону GD, там даже в документации есть примеры

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста)

```
.content{  width:50px;  height:50px;  text-align:center;  background: green;  color: #fff;  font-size: 22px;  display: table-cell;  border-radius: 100%;  position: relative;  vertical-align: middle;}
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/genesisplus/ztfLmxo2/8/)

Comment: не подходит. нужно на php. у вас css

Comment: если вам для сохранения картинки, то была такая тема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524447/Создание-картинки-из-html-тегов-с-помощью-php

Comment: сохранять не обязательно, хотя бы просто вывод через тег img

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно написать функцию для рисования прямоугольника с закругленными углами, то есть с круглыми краями. При указании нужного радиуса это будет казаться кругом.

```
function imagefillroundedrect($image, $x, $y, $cx, $cy, $rad, $color)
{
    imagefilledrectangle($image, $x, $y + $rad, $cx, $cy - $rad, $color);
    imagefilledrectangle($image, $x + $rad, $y, $cx - $rad, $cy, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($image, $x + $rad, $y + $rad, $rad * 2, $rad * 2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($image, $x + $rad, $cy - $rad, $rad * 2, $rad * 2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($image, $cx - $rad, $cy - $rad, $rad * 2, $rad * 2, $color);
    imagefilledellipse($image, $cx - $rad, $y + $rad, $rad * 2, $rad * 2, $color);
}
```

Простое использование:

```
// создаем изображение 50 x 50 пикселей
$image = imagecreate(50, 50);
// Заливаем фон с неким цветом
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 137, 137, 137);
// Избавляемся от некого цвета
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);
// Рисование круга с зеленым (RGB 0, 128, 0) цветом 
imagefillroundedrect($image, 0, 0, 50, 50, 24.5, imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 128, 0));

// Путь к шрифту
$font = '/dc/Tahoma.ttf';
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
// Отрисовка буквы
imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 20, 35, $white, $font, 'I');

header('content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

В результате получаем картинку с зеленым кругом и прозрачным фоном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]