# Отправить сообщение в табличном виде в мессенджер (Viber, Messenger, WhatsApp и др.)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sendmessage

Есть БД и приложение заливающее в эту БД строки информации с названием, датой и суммой.
Хочу пересылать информацию полученную с **SQLite** в сторонний мессенджер  конкретному пользователю. Например в **Viber** текстовым сообщением в формате:

```
Название / дата  / цена
----------------------
Сахар    / 17.05 / 1$
Молоко   / 18.05 / 2$
Молоко   / 18.06 / 2$
----------------------
Кол-во продуктов: 3
Сумма: 4$
```

Вытащить информацию с БД и залить в текстовый документ или в **CSV** - могу.
А вот потом передать все это в виде таблицы - не могу сообразить как.

Пока что могу отправлять только текстовое сообщение в одну строку. 
Примеры которые находил в основном как залить картинку, текст или файл.
Направьте в нужное русло,

Comment: Может быть вам надо просто бежать циклом по колонкам таблицы и значения в строку фигачить? И каждую строку от другой переносом строки отгораживать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я так думал делать, залить в строку с переносами. Но чтобы ровная табличка была - нужно поиграться с отступами разделителей (так как названия разные по длине char-ов).

Comment: Ну да, наверное надо какой-то код написать который будет находить самую длинную строку в каждой колонке и получить кол-во символов в каждой строке. Вот и получится выровнено после добавления пробелов для коротких значений

Comment: Искал какую-то либу для автоматического парсинга с CSV или другого текстового файла и последующей отправкой адресату в месенджер. Искал как реализовать средствами самих месенджеров - ненашел. Проверял с Переносами вариант - он работает, хоть и кривовата табличка. Наверное придется идти по пути упрощения если не будет какого-то более усовершенствованого варианта.

Comment: Вряд ли какая-то либа существует - слишком узкая задача. Таблицы вообще боль на мобилках. Они только в WebView нормально (условно нормально) работают. Думаю помимо составления текста с переносами и пробелами вручную способов нет. И даже в этом случае будет проблема не помещения строки таблиц в размер экрана. Будут автопереносы и будет некрасиво и нечитаемо. Может стоит рассмотреть генерирование HTML таблицы на к-л сайте и кидание ссылки на эту страницу. Т.е. идеального варианта всё одно сделать никак нельзя. Придётся идти на компромисы с костылями.

Comment: Та, да. Проблемы маленьких экранов (или  если будет глобальная настройка большого шрифта) - не избежать наверное. Оформите вариант с переносами как ответ - если, пока доеду домой никто не кинет другого варианта - то приму его как оптимальную реализацию.

Comment: А может присылать пользователю картинкой? а также ссылку уже на страницу с красивой таблицей.

Comment: @KoVadim, я примерно подобное предлагал чуть выше как вариант) Вот даже когда-то задавал вопрос про таблицу в картинку и там есть в ответе сайт, коий можно для этого заюзать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521893/17609

Comment: @KoVadim Я хотел какой то таблицей, но понимаю уже что текстом это пока оптимальный вариант. Относительно картинки, ее нужно сгенерить, а потом получатель еще должен ее загрузить для просмотра, а в вайбере, например, картинка до загрузки  показывается как обрезанный по краям превью - неудобно. Ссылку я на документ на гугл-диске делал, но ее тоже нужно открывать, тем более переходить по ссылке - лишние действия, это же еще нужно перейти по этой ссылке.

Comment: Для Вайбере можно так подготовить картинку, что когда ее обрежут, выглядела нормальнр

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное вам надо просто бежать циклом по колонкам таблицы и значения в строку фигачить. И каждую строку от другой переносом строки отгораживать.

Также, надо какой-то код написать который будет находить самую длинную строку в каждой колонке и получить, в итоге, максимальное кол-во символов в каждой строке. Вот и получится выровнено после добавления пробелов для коротких значений.

Вряд ли какая-то либа существует, которая решит эту задачу - слишком узкая она. Таблицы вообще боль на мобилках. Они только в WebView нормально (условно нормально) работают. Думаю помимо составления текста с переносами и пробелами вручную способов нет. И даже в этом случае будет проблема не помещения строки таблиц в размер экрана (из-за маленького экрана или большого размера шрифта в настройках девайса). Будут автопереносы и будет некрасиво и нечитаемо. Может стоит рассмотреть генерирование HTML таблицы на к-л сайте и кидание ссылки на эту страницу. Т.е. идеального варианта всё одно сделать никак нельзя. Придётся идти на компромиссы с костылями.

Comment: Буду делать как текст с переносами. Это действительно оптимальный вариант для формирования подобия таблицы. Ссылки и картинки - довольно сложны для юзания на стороне пользователя.